# How to change rainlab.user::mail.invite to have activation link

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-user-plugin

I am using rainlabs user plugin but I do not allow users to register but I add new users manually but I still want new users to activate their account I thought I could just change the mail.invite template to

```
Hello {{ name }}

A user account has been created for you. Please use the following login and password to sign in:

{% partial 'panel' body %}
- Login: `{{ login }}`
- Password: `{{ password|raw }}`
{% endpartial %}

We need to verify that this is your email address.

Please click the link below to confirm your account:

{% partial 'button' url=link type='positive' body %}
Confirm account
{% endpartial %}

After signing in you should change your password as soon as possible.
```

which partially works but the button does not include the activation URL any more is there a better solution for this or will I need to alter the plugin

Comment: Did you actually edit the template or did you change which one it was using?

Comment: Hi Pettis I edited the template  but when I receive the email the button has no url I tested to make sure everything else was working fine with the other methods of activation and reactivation and they work I hoped I could just copy and paste from one template to another which I have done before but this did not work this time